# Outside flood light problem

Tags: electrical

A two light outdoor flood light fixture has stopped working.  I have replaced the bulbs, checked the circuit breaker, the GFI, the switch (including bypassing the switch).  I have also checked for electricity inside the box to which the fixture is attached.  No current is present in the box, even with the switch on.  Any additional suggestions to try?

Comment: Is there current at the switch?

Comment: Yes, there is current at the switch, but when I bypassed the switch, STILL no current at the fixture or its box.

Comment: Did anything change between the point when the light worked, and it not working (hung a picture on the wall above the switch or near the light, lightning strike, changed the fixture, changed a receptacle or other electrical device, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a fault between the switch and the fixture. Search for nearby junction boxes to see if there's a bad connection somewhere. Do what you can to trace the line, especially if it goes up to an attic or down to an exposed basement. You should also check if the problem is a faulty hot (no current from the hot to a known good ground) or a fault neutral (no continuity between the neutral and a known good ground) to narrow your search. If you can't find the fault, you'll need to run a new line from the switch to the fixture.